# How to setup a network between a windows computer and a linux computer?

Tags: networking, arch-linux, windows

I connected my Windows computer to my Linux computer with an Ethernet cable.  The problem is that the Linux interface enp5s0 doesn't acquire an IP and when I try to ping the Windows computer it says network unreachable. I have tried `systemctl start dhcpcd@enp5s0.service` but it fails to start with

> soliciting dhcp lease timed out

Which should be normal, but then how do I set an IP for the Linux machine in this network of two? And how do I enable the Linux machine to ping and download files from the Windows machine?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration#Static_IP_address shows you how to setup a static IP.  You may want to set up Samba for file sharing.

Comment: are you sure you are either a cross-over cable between your two computers or at least one of the network interfaces have signal auto-sensing capability ?

Comment: Or are you connecting these computers to a switch/hub/router ?

Comment: @MelBurslan:  Fortunately, many Ethernet adapters from the last decade support both types of cables so hopefully one of them supports it.

Comment: Not exactly "Ethernet adapters from the last decade"; it is the GigaBit ethernet protocol that allows that. If you have a 100Mbps NIC (for instance a raspberry  board), you would better have a crossover cable.

Comment: Sorry to contradict you @RuiFRibeiro, but I've seen 100mbps adapters that support both cables 12 years ago.

Comment: @JuliePelletier your first link worked easily with the manual setup example

Answer (score 2):

In order to acquire an IP adress on the Linux machine using the DHCP method you have to install an DHCP-Server on the Windows machine first and configure it.

I assume that is not really what you want. In order to exchange network packages between both hosts you have to assure that both hosts are on the same network. In this hardware setting the best way to do so is to manually set up static network configurations on both hosts.

**Configuration on the Windows (7?) machine:**

When the cable is connected via ethernet your networking notifier in the windows task bar should show a wired connection symbol (or a spinning circle notifying you it is trying to automatically get an IP via DHCP).

Click on the symbol and then open the network and sharing center. On the right hand side of the upcoming window you should see something like an underlined "LAN-connection 1". Click on it an then go to "Properties". In the upcoming list mark "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)" and then again click on "Properties". Now check "Use the following IP-Adresses" (or something like that - I only have the german version of Windows on my screen and can't tell what the exact english translation is). Now type in the following fields:

- IP-adress: 10.0.0.1
- subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
- gateway: 10.0.0.2 (does not matter as there is no way out of your small two host network. Using the following configuration steps, your Linux host will be the gateway host)

Confirm by clicking "OK".

**Configuration on the Linux machine (Debian/Ubuntu):**

Open up a terminal window and do the following commands (as superuser):

```
ifconfig enp5s0 up
ifconfig enp5s0 10.0.0.2
ifconfig enp5s0 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

You have now set up a small network containing the two hosts with the Linux machine being the gateway host (when the Linux host has a second interface connected to an WAN and the forwarding is set up properly then it can act as a "real" internet-gateway for the windows machine).

Verify the setup using the ping command on the both hosts (the terminal can be used on both OSes to do so).

On the Linux machine:

```
ping 10.0.0.1
```

On the Windows machine:

```
ping 10.0.0.2
```

And both should consecutively show up successfully issued ping packets.